# google sheet query contains an exact match to find the value from comma separated cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here's the link to the example google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P2h9GEr7GUkfYP61HzDS0_Gdqf-l7M9sGh9Ds8Qyzxc/edit?usp=sharing

In column A (see below), the texts are separated by comma, and now I want to use a query to find all the rows that contains `test 1` but not the rows with `test 10`.

```
test 1, test 10, test 27
test 10
test 1
test 29, test 1
test 20, test 10
```

I used a query `=query(A:B,"Select B where A contains 'test 1'")` but it will return not only `test 1` but also `test 10`.
Also, the source data cannot be changed (`test 1` cannot be changed to `test1`), what's the formula to use to find all rows with `test 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using `filter()`

```
=FILTER(B:B,REGEXMATCH(A:A,"test 1(?:,|$)"))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, works beautifully! can you please explain a bit more in your answer, what does ?:,|$ do?

Comment: well its being setup to match `test 1` end with either a comma OR the end($)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex if you use the `matches` operator

```
=query(A:B,"Select B where A matches '.*test 1?(,|$).*'")
```